# Adding rows of values into textarea on press of button

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, textarea

I'm trying to make a small POS system. And in that i need to add different items into a list before 'making the sale' (which i will later be inserting into a database as separate INSERT statements)

Right now i'm having an issue with the button which add the sales into the text area. It worked fine when i had only one sale to enter. But started to give a `NullPointerException` when i made the values into an array and looped it..

Here is my code:

```
if (action.getSource() == btnAdd)
       {
            //values
            String[] salesNo= null;
            String[] itemNo = null;
            String[] staffNo = null;
            String[] customerNo = null; 
            Date date= new Date();
            int[] quantity = null;
            double[] finalprice = null;


            //inserting itemno------------------------
            String findItemNoCommand = "SELECT itemNo FROM `item` WHERE itemName = '" + itemList.getSelectedItem() + "'";
            try 
            {
                itemNo[count] = viewValue(conn, findItemNoCommand);
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //inserting customerno------------------------
            customerNo[count] = (String) customerList.getSelectedItem();


            staffNo[count] = "null"; // to be developed

            //checking and insertion of quantity------------------------
            double tempquantity =  Double.parseDouble(quantityText.getText()); 
            if(tempquantity % 1 == 0)
            {
                quantity[count] = (int) tempquantity; //Checking if the value is an integer
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(alphaPOS,
                        "You need to enter a whole number for Quantity",
                        "ERROR",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            //calculating final price from price of item------------------------
            String tempprice = null;
            String findPriceCommand = "SELECT sellingprice FROM `item` WHERE itemNo = '" + itemNo + "'";
            try 
            {
                tempprice = viewValue(conn, findPriceCommand);
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Double price = Double.parseDouble(tempprice);
            finalprice[count] = quantity[count] * price;
            //------------------------------------------------------------------


            salesdata[count++] = new Sales(salesNo[count], itemNo[count], staffNo[count], customerNo[count], date, quantity[count], finalprice[count]);

            salesTextArea.setText(" "+"\n");
            int i =0;

            while (salesdata[i] != null)
            {
                salesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].finalprice, 2);
                salesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].quantity, 2);
                salesTextArea.insert("\t" + dateFormat.format(salesdata[i].date), 2);
                salesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].customerNo, 2);
                salesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].staffNo, 2);
                salesTextArea.insert("" + salesdata[i].itemNo, 2);
                //salesTextArea.insert("\n", 2);
                i++;
            }
            salesTextArea.insert("Item No \t StaffNo\t CustomerNo \t Date and Time \t\t Quantity \t Final Price", 0);          }
```

`salesdata` is declared here: `static Sales salesdata[] = new Sales[50];`

The code compiled fine, but I'm getting the exception. Any clue why?
Any help or hints as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you declare your array as `null`, and then immediately try to write a value to it.

```
String[] itemNo = null;
itemNo[count] = viewValue(conn, findItemNoCommand);
```

You need to initialize it with some non-null value if you want to store anything in it.

Comment: @ShifaTsar You want to initialize it like this: `String[] itemNo = new String[size];`, assuming you know the size it needs to be. If you don't I'd suggest looking into `ArrayList`, which can grow as you use it.